# Unity - рендеринг модели в независимой среде с альфа каналом

Tags: unity3d

[image: Пример]Есть инвентарь с системой ячеек, и предметы в нем. Каждый предмет имеет свою иконку. Нужно каким-то образом рендерить модель под определённым ракурсом, не учитывая свет главной сцены и обьекты на ней, так ещё и с альфа каналом, который будет содержать только силуэт модели. Первые две задачи решаются слоями, а третья (наличие альфа канала) - не знаю. Сложность в том, что использовать заранее отрендеренные изображения - нельзя, конфигурация оружия легко изменяется игроком.

В качестве примера привожу игру PUBG, и её инвентарь, в котором отрисовка оружия и персонажа являются тем, что мне нужно.

Comment: [RawImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html), [RenderTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html), [Camera.cullingMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-cullingMask.html), [Light.cullingMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light-cullingMask.html). На рендере камеры нет скайбокса.

Comment: @Yaroslav Выходное изображение будет с альфа каналом?